# Ship collision with coin not working properly

Tags: xcode, swift

I created a game where the player has to collect coins. Now for some reason when there are a lot of coins on the screen to grab, when the ship collides with the coin it will go straight through the current coin its colliding with and removes the last coin that is added to the screen. How can I make it so that the actual coin that the collision happens with becomes removed from the screen?

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(shipCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(obstacleCategory)) != 0 {
        ship.removeFromParent()
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(shipCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(coinCategory)) != 0 {
        coin.removeFromParent()
        playerScore = playerScore + 1
        playerScoreUpdate()
    }


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if currentTime - self.lastMissileAdded > 1 {
        self.lastMissileAdded = currentTime + 1
        self.addMissile()
    }

    // Current time + 6 takes longer to respawn coins
    if currentTime - self.lastCoinAdded > 1 {
        self.lastCoinAdded = currentTime + 0
        self.addCoin()
    }

    // Current time + 6 takes longer to respawn coins
    //if currentTime - self.lastDiamondAdded > 1 {
      //  self.lastDiamondAdded = currentTime + 1
        //self.addDiamond()
    //}

    self.moveBackground()
    self.moveObstacle()
    self.moveCoin()
    //self.moveDiamond()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `coin` that the `ship` has collided with change the code in inside the second condition in your `didBeginContact` function. You have to remove the node that belongs to the `secondBody`. In your code you are just removing a `coin global variable`. This is why it doesn't work when there are other coins in the scene.

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(shipCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(coinCategory)) != 0 {
    secondBody.node?.removeFromParent() // Changed line.
    playerScore = playerScore + 1
    playerScoreUpdate()
}
```